# Unexpected Error Occurred ServiceStack Redis Client

Tags: redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

Am getting an error while manipulating Hashes with Servicestack pooled redisClientsManager.

here is how i have registered the IOC

```
private static IRedisClientsManager redisClientsManager;
redisClientsManager =  new PooledRedisClientManager("host:6379");
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => redisClientsManager);
container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetClient());
container.Register<IRepository>(c => new Repository(c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()));
```

And Here is how am using it in Repository,

```
IRedisClientsManager manager;
public repository(IRedisClientsManager mgr)
{
 this.manager=mgr;
}
```

//Method to talk to redis

```
using(var red = manager.getClient())
{
  //do stuff with Other datatype except Hashes WORKS
}
//Error raised here
using(var redHash = manager.getClient())
{
  //do stuff with Hashes DOESNT WORKS
}
```

Error:
    Unexpected Error:* 0...., Redis response Error
Any Suggestions on how to use PooledRedisClientManager Threadsafe.!

**Adding Stack trace :**

Message:Unexpected reply: *0, sPort: 6379, LastCommand:

> at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.CreateResponseError(String error)
>      at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.ParseSingleLine(String r)
>      at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendExpectData(Byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs)
>      at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.EvalShaStr(String sha1, Int32 numberKeysInArgs, Byte[][] keys)
>      at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.ExecLuaShaAsString(String sha1, String[] keys, String[] args)
>      at Services.Data.Repository.GetMo(geoJ , DateTime , String ) in \Data\Repository.cs:line 169
>      at Services.Api.getMService.Any(getM request) in \Api\getMService.cs:line 15
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object )
>      at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequestContext requestContext, Object instance, TRequest request)

Comment: Please provide an example of code that doesn't work, you can create a [Live C# Redis Example on Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=54e452bb1e86e132068a595d7e72d1a6).

Comment: @mythz I tried recreating the problem but was unable to reproduce. Am implementing Repository Pattern ,where i register Repository with constructor instantiated Clients Manager as shown above.

Comment: Right, but we'll need to be able to repro the issue in order to identify it. Everything looks ok except CacheClient should be a singleton (so remove ReuseScope.None) and `GetClient()` should be PascalCase. Also you don't need an array for `new PooledRedisClientManager("host:6379")`

Comment: @mythz i have updated my question with changes and Stack trace. But still getting the error.any leads would be very helpful.

Comment: This error is a result of calling `ExecLuaShaAsString`. Does your LUA code your Service is executing return a string? Maybe try calling `ExecLuaSha` which can support variable LUA response types.

Comment: @mythz Genius ..worked like charm !

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get an `Message:Unexpected reply` Error when calling a LUA script you need to ensure that what the script is returning matches with the RedisClient API you're calling, which in this case of `RedisClient.ExecLuaShaAsString()` expects a `string`.

If you're unsure of what Type your LUA script returns you can call the more reusable `ExecLuaSha` which returns a complex `RedisText` type that can support a number of different LUA response types.